# How to fix the size of a table having a sticky header as well as sorting and searching?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tablesorter, sticky

I have a table with sorting searching and sticky table header.
The first problem I am facing is not able to stick the header with the table. On scroll it it sticking to window.
Second I am not able to re size the table width and height. When I keep it inside a `div` tag then sticky header is not working

Please help me how to achieve that.

```
<script id="js">$(function(){
    $("table").tablesorter({
        widthFixed : true,
        showProcessing: true,
        headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}', 
        // Add icon for jui theme; new in v2.7!
        widgets: [ 'uitheme', 'zebra', 'stickyHeaders', 'filter' ],
        widgetOptions: {
           // extra css class name applied to the sticky header row (tr) - changed in v2.11
          stickyHeaders : '',
          // adding zebra striping, using content and default styles - the ui css removes the background from default
          // even and odd class names included for this demo to allow switching themes
          zebra   : ["ui-widget-content even", "ui-state-default odd"],
          // use uitheme widget to apply defauly jquery ui (jui) class names
          // see the uitheme demo for more details on how to change the class names
          uitheme : 'jui'
        }
    });

});</script>
```

This is the js file for css

```
  <script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
```

Comment: The stickyHeaders widget is currently not able to "stick" to its parent element; it only sticks to the browser window. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/295) already posted, I just haven't gotten around to it yet.

Comment: Thnaks for the reply...If solution comes up please share it..

Answer (score 0):

try to do same as what I've did on jsfiddle:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/Ziad/2EZjJ/][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now a [css sticky header widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-css-sticky-header.html), but it is still in beta testing.

Although the currently available version shared above doesn't allow attaching the sticky header to its parent, there is a [demo in the works](http://jsfiddle.net/zwpLT/10/) with this functionality (see [this issue](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/453#issuecomment-29954870) for updates). The last issue to overcome is getting the caption to stick properly in Firefox (`cssStickyHeaders_addCaption` option).

```
$(function () {

    $("table").tablesorter({
        widgets: ['cssStickyHeaders'],
        widgetOptions: {
            cssStickyHeaders_offset: 0,
            cssStickyHeaders_addCaption: true,
            cssStickyHeaders_attachTo: null
        }
    });

});
```

I would appreciate help with finding any other issues that would need to be addressed, besides the borders not staying with the sticky cells (LOL, I have no idea how to fix that).